# PHP - What is the best way to add a value with array existing value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following code to sum a value `$x` with all the existing value in an array `$arr`:

```
$arr = array(
   '0' => 2,
   '1' => 3
);

foreach( $arr as $key => $value ) {
   $arr[ $key ] = $arr[ $key ] + $x;
}
```

But the code is too slow when the size of the array increases and time is a fact for a particular application. So I am interested to know is there any other alternative way to perform the operation?

- Thanks

Comment: You could try `$key => &$value` and `$value += $x;`.  Not sure if it will make much of a difference though.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it using `+=`. This should make it a little bit faster:

```
$arr = array( '0' => 2, '1' => 3);

foreach( $arr as $key => $value ) {
   $arr[ $key ] += $x;
}
```

You can test it here: [enter link description here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e32a719aa9618a848e0d30c367890883b14f8e4c)

Answer (score 0):

With `array_map()` you can do this kind of manipulation;

```
$arr = array(
   '0' => 2,
   '1' => 3
);

$x = 1;

$newArr = array_map(function($value) use ($x) {
    return $value + $x;
}, $arr);

print_r($newArr);
```

Will produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
```

Comment: Will it improve speed?

Comment: I think it's faster than a for/foreach, because array_map is a native php function.